# Python output streamline in table with print command

Tags: python, linux, scripting, formatting

In Python script i am reading command output and putting them in loop to extract specific column, I am trying to format output so it looks good but it little cluttered if few character more in result. I how do i make them nice look?

```
for i in data:
            print i[2], '|', i[12], '\t|', i[9], '\t\t\t|', i[24].split('@')[-1]
```

Output:

```
[root@tux work]# ./foo.py
2015-04-24 10:26:44 | RINGING   | 17654742161                   |
2015-04-24 10:26:44 | RINGING   | 00100017654742161                     |
2015-04-24 10:13:52 | ACTIVE    | 18146252950                   | 72.xx.xx.120
2015-04-24 10:24:25 | ACTIVE    | 17323576331                   | 72.xx.xx.120
```

I want out put like following

```
[root@tux work]# ./foo.py
    2015-04-24 10:26:44 | RINGING   | 17654742161                   |
    2015-04-24 10:26:44 | RINGING   | 00100017654742161             |
    2015-04-24 10:13:52 | ACTIVE    | 18146252950                   | 72.xx.xx.120
    2015-04-24 10:24:25 | ACTIVE    | 17323576331                   | 72.xx.xx.120
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use *string formatting*. According to your samples, which can be something like this:

```
for i in data:
    params = [i[2], i[12], i[9], i[24].split('@')[-1]]
    print '{:20s} | {:10s} | {:20s} | {:16s}'.format(*params)
```

As already commented by @twalberg, you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)